# How much self-promotion is too much?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam, self-promotion

For specifics: I am asking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74858501/13376511).

I recently saw an answer that did indeed answer the question, but then also linked to a youtube channel and asked for others to like and subscribe. I can understand linking to a video that you made about an issue (and that video does seem answer the question), but having half of your answer being essentially self-promotion seems excessive. Should answers like this be just edited, or do they warrant a spam flag?

Comment: I don't know much about tkinter, but that answer doesn't even seem related to the question originally asked.

Comment: "I recently saw an answer that did indeed answer the question". Are you sure about that? To me, it doesn't appear to be addressing the issue in the question. It does appear to be addressing a *different* `utf-8` encoding issue, but not one related to the question.

Answer (score 19):

Gut-take on this answer - I'd flag it as spam.

I'm not sure there's a lot that editing could do to make this answer any better - the answer isn't really addressing the OP's concern to begin with, from what I can tell - and it's just a whole plug for their own content on another platform.  This just smells like spam to me.

Comment: I also found a self-promoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71464864/3448527 and flagged as spam, which the mod declined it but then deleted the answer with this comment `I deleted this because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it, especially if you are linking to content that you authored, as that might be seen as overtly self-promotional. Add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable.`

Comment: @dippas I mean, it's not spam, so, that's a correct decline. Certainly could have been better attributed, but that doesn't make it spam.

Comment: @KevinB that's the closest flag we have for self-promoted content without using a custom flag

Comment: Flagging things incorrectly just because we want to avoid using a custom flag is detrimental. Spam flags carry a very heavy penalty.

Comment: @KevinB That one seems "spammy" enough to me. I agree with dippas. I've also seen answers mod-deleted as "spam or rude or abusive" for less. I guess the point I'm making is that it appears to be somewhat subjective, even for mods.

Comment: @DrewReese:  There's a ***stark*** difference between [a link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/175248) and [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/175248).  The flag decline was absolutely correct there.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't say anything about a link-only answer. The linked-to answer from dippas is simply along the lines of "You can do [X], see my [Y on one of my personal github]". Sure, it's effectively a link-only answer, but as I said, this is subjective. *You* appear to *not* think it spammy, I do, Blackgreen didn't, and as I also said, I've seen mods delete answers as "spam" for less.

Comment: @DrewReese:  The callsign of spam is that it's usually something that drives revenue for another entity.  Linking to your GitHub?  Eh, probably not, if the repo is open and not locked behind a firewall.  Linking to social media?  More than likely spam.  Linking to a paywalled thing? Absolutely.  If you're making money from it and you're not *saying* you're making money from it, it's spam.  If you're looking to scam some folks with a dodgy link, it's spam.  If you're just using your GitHub repo as a reference but don't add that context in, that's not really spam at all, just a link-only answer.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, thanks. Not looking to disagree here, just pointing out observations. ‍♂️

Comment: @Makoto And yet the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), which is linked to from the text in the spam flag dialog, does not equate spam with revenue at all.

Comment: Does the user deserve to lose 100 rep for linking to a github repo they own without properly attributing it?