# Spam versus unsolicited self-promotion, and when to use the spam flag (or not)

Tags: discussion, flags, help-center

*Context: this question is based on the comments from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422276/70345).*

When you go to flag content as spam, you are presented with the following text:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

That URL links to a Help Centre page that starts with:

> How to not be a spammer

but goes on to talk about unsolicited self-promotion (and the URL contains the text "promotion" too), thereby conflating the two terms. This conflation is also generally in line with the fact that many users consider spam to be anything unsolicited, which on this site would generally include self-promotion.

The waters are further muddied because [guidance about how to use spam flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/175248) also does not explicitly mention commercial purposes, only unsolicited ones - i.e. it appears to be in line with the Help Centre's conflation of spam and unsolicited self-promotion.

However, as per that same guidance, the penalties for content judged to be correctly flagged as spam are far more severe than for other flags that would generally result in said content being removed - including content that is **unsolicited self-promotion for non-commercial purposes**. This would suggest that contrary to the language used in the Help Centre and guidance, spam is indeed different to unsolicited self-promotion and should be treated as such.

In short, when it comes to flagging there is apparently a very clear distinction between spam and unsolicited self-promotion; but guidance on using the spam flag, or not, does not make this distinction. This is confusing for users attempting to choose the most correct flag reason - how should we amend the guidance to remove this potential for confusion?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354543/how-to-distinguish-between-spam-and-non-spam-answer-and-how-to-bring-it-into-mo

Answer (score 6):

I think Kevin B's comment on [the answer in question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422276/13376511) perfectly conveys the confusion:

> Does the user deserve to lose 100 rep for linking to a github repo they own without properly attributing it?

In the answer's [original question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422274/13376511) (which I wrote), the user self-promoting themself posted a substandard answer and then filled half of their answer with a plea for others to like and subscribe to their YouTube channel. This kind of behavior seems much more likely to warrant a spam flag, however in a way it is somewhat similar to the hypothetical situation in Kevin B's comment.

I think the only time a post should be considered for being spam is if 1) the post was created to promote the author, not to help share knowledge; and 2) the product being promoted is for commercial purposes.

Under these criteria, linking to a freely-licensed GitHub repo that the user owns and forgetting to attribute it does not warrant a full out -100 rep punishment. However, filling half of your answer with "like and subscribe" does because a YouTube channel is more likely to generate ad revenue and does deserve the punishment.

A more murky situation would be if an employee of service ends an otherwise non-spam answer with a single sentence along the lines of "Alternatively, you can use [unattributed service] to do this for you.". IMO, if the answer solves the question, then should be kept and does not deserve a flag. The punishment does not fit the crime when only one problematic sentence needs to be edited out.

So, I think a fairer guidance might be as follows:

> Promoting a product or service for commercial purposes is the sole purpose for why the post was created.

Comment: The suggestion is good, but I wonder if "commercial purposes" implies that the purpose favors the poster and if I share a link to a payed product from someone else (where I wouldn't gain anything from it) would also warrant that flag. I would say yes, but is it obvious for other users as well?

Comment: Note: Social capital is still capital and can be converted into actual revenue. Effectively the person is the product, so posts that do little or nothing besides promoting the person are still spam. A post that links to a gihub repo is a bad post worthy of downvotes and probably deletion, but adding pleas for likes and follows onto a poorly conceived post pushes it the rest of the way.

Comment: I agree with 1, but not 2. I don't think it needs to be a "commercial product" to cross the line. After all, many "non-profit" labeled entities make millions in revenue or spend the entirety of what they raise on political causes.

Comment: @KevinB Maybe "monetary value" would be better wording then?

Comment: I would just leave it at value.  "the product being promoted creates value for the user." though, tbf, that's mostly covered by #1.

Comment: I *strongly* disagree with the proposed change to the **short** description of the flag, because it effectively permits a user to post 1,000 answers promoting *anything* which isn't for commercial purposes, and people *do* spew out large quantities of posts which promote their non-commercial thing (although, we tend to catch them *way* before they get to 1,000 posts about it).

Comment: While I agree that merely forgetting to add disclosure in a single post that provides a *real* answer to the question which is *actually* asked isn't something for which a -100 rep penalty should be applied, how to handle situations that are more complex than that (and they almost all are) is a judgement call. While it's a judgement which individual users make when choosing to raise a spam flag or an "in need of moderator intervention" flag, the final call usually ends up being made either by the consensus of 6 users, or by a moderator.

Comment: If someone feels the call was wrong, they can raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag and explain why they think the call was incorrect, providing more context than might have been available when people were flagging and/or when the flag(s) were handled. I've raised many such flags (both prior to being a moderator and on sites where I'm not a moderator). I don't recall any such flag that I've raised which has been marked anything other than "helpful" (although there might have been some), and *most* of the time the additional context has resulted in slightly different handling.

Comment: @KevinB: This answer doesn't say "commercial **product**".  Linking a monetized youtube video counts as a commercial **purpose**.  Linking something on github that only builds social capital is only indirectly commercial, and more of a gray area where we should consider intent: was it just a link-only answer?  Or is it not even an answer at all, just looking for an excuse to dump a link to your project. Linking a useful library you wrote can be ok in a comment, or maybe as *part* of an answer (which shows how to use it to solve the specific problem, or shows how the library does it internally)

Comment: @PeterCordes same difference

Comment: I don't understand why 2) even matters. E.g. there is a user who was spamming (this is the best word to outline the situation) with their "proof" of decidability of halting problem. They did it on multiple sites, and multiple times on a single site. But, since there is no commercial purpose involved, it is not considered spam? Doesn't make sense to me. (And I believe that losing 100 reputation is totally deserved in such a case)